# If I pre-order HOTS can I give the Beta key to someone else?

Tags: starcraft-2

If I pre-order HOTS now, can I give my beta key to someone else to use with their account and then when the game is released properly still play with my own account?

Comment: I don't think this is a question we can answer without a specific article on this.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, yes. In my case, I ordered from Amazon, and they emailed me a beta key. The beta key is not linked to anything yet, so anyone can use it. To attach it to a specific Battle.net account, the owner of the account just has to log in to battle.net and apply the key, which will then give them access to the beta.

Comment: this. i already had a beta key before preordering HoTS. Keys are normal keys, with preorder you just get one when other people can't have it. But it's not bound to your account till you use it (that would be stupid of them: if they already bind a key to your account, they could simply enable the account to play the beta)